# Penetration testing with Perl non-object-oriented

Tags: perl, sockets, penetration-testing

This is one of the very first times I have written on a forum. Usually just reading is enough to find what I am looking for.

I have a decent foundation with Perl and I would like to do penetration testing with it. My problem is that every tutorial or book I find works with LWP,  which is object-oriented, and I frankly hate object-oriented programming (it doesn't make sense to me as much as functional programming). If there is any CPAN module to do "Web programming"  that may work without OOP,  Google is very shy to tell me.

Even though it must be lots of work,  I would like to write a LWP-like module but with functional style of programming instead of OOP.

My main question is where do I start? I found very little on socket programming with Perl that doesn't use LWP or some non-core Perl module. The less I would use CPAN the more I'd be happy.

I understand it's a little like reinventing the wheel but I want to do it mostly for fun and sometimes it's the best way to learn.

Comment: socket() is your friend? http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Sockets%3a-Client%2fServer-Communication To which non core module are you referring to?

Comment: I think the link you just gave me is exactly what I need. Strangely it was never brought up on my Google searches.. In any case thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`socket`, `bind`, `listen` and `accept` would be the most basic functions you are looking for to implement server-side functionality; `socket` and `connect` are the client-side ones.

The section ***Sockets: Client/Server Communication*** in [`perldoc perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) should give further advice. The functions mentioned there directly map to the corresponding system calls. More low-level (and more painful) than that you couldn't hope to find.

Being a passionate hater of overwhelmingly complex and bloate OOP approaches myself, I'd like to give you the advice to take a look at the way OOP is done in Perl. Maybe you'll fall as deep in love with it as I once did.

Being nothing more than `bless`ed hashes themselves. Being unwilling to use any Perl objects is more or less equivalent to being unwilling to use any hashes at all.

Comment: Thanks mikyra. I Went over the oop chapter of beginning Perl at www.perl.org, I do understand the basic of it I think. For some reason oop doesn't seem structured to me,  I don't know how it is with other languages as Perl and bash are the only ones I know so far. I love Perl and wanted to write programs that would be useful to me,  since am also slowly trying to dive into the pentesting world I thought I could join both. Now if really writing a LWP like module in functional programming is less efficient than oop,  maybe I should try and learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly encourage you to learn the way Perl handles object-oriented programming. I believe that it is by far the best introduction to OOP as it hides nothing, and all the mechanisms are exposed. A class is a package, a method is a subroutine, and your constructor is just another method

You will probably not need to create Perl classes yourself if you are writing small utility programs, but as soon as you want to use other people's libraries you will probably find yourself needing to know how to use OO Perl

`LWP` is perhaps one of the more complex libraries, as it has a number of different classes, but remember that [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) has to describe the functionality in its entirety and, at least initially, you won't be using much of what is available

To fetch a simple web page, all you need to do is create a `LWP::UserAgent` object and use it to `get` the URL you're interested in

```
use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->get('http://www.example.com/');
```

You now have an `HTTP::Response` object, `$res`, and you can read the [documentation for that class](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) to see what methods it supports, such as checking the status and retrieving the HTTP headers and the body of the message

That is pretty much all there is to simple LWP programming, but there are many options available to allow for more complex situations if you need them

Finally, it's worth pointing out that there is *already* a functional HTTP module called [`LWP::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple). If you want the very basic functionality then you can write just

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $body = get('http://www.example.com/');
```

and you have retrieved a web page. Of course this doesn't allow you to examine the status of the HTTP transaction and the headers in the response message, so if you need that capability or more then you need to use the standard LWP interface

Comment: Thanks Borodin. I belive perl's opp is hiding too much of the underlyings from me. By that I mean even tho i can fetch Web pages, make user agents etc very easily, i still don't know how they works. Honestly if I had time I would gladly learn C. I'm a welder working 6/7 making 12h shifts.. I wanna "rewrite LWP" so I can learn how things works, not necessarily cause I don't like LWP. True,  oop doesn't appeal me but again,  it's more for the learning process. I hope i explained myself clearly. (am a French guy lol) thanks again for all your replies!!

Comment: Your English is very clear, thank you. `LWP` in turn relies on [`IO::Socket::INET`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::INET) for an OOP interface to internet-domain sockets, and you should look there for help with how to implement a functional module. But you have a huge task ahead of you, as the implementation pretty much relies on *black boxes* that provide higher-level "primitives" based on the API for the level below

Comment: If it was only alot of work it wouldn't be too bad, maybe I should have add that about 7 months ago I didn't even know what linux was exactly... It's more like an infinite mountain am trying to climb ;) In any ways, thanks alot for your help. I'll try to post some code once and IF I finaly get something decent.